# SVG does not appear in Firefox

Tags: html, xml, firefox, svg

I have an embedded SVG in an HTML page. Everything works fine, but not with Firefox...

I've read that Firefox is quite rigorous interpreting SVGs so I tried a lot of things in order to make my SVG perfect. But according to Firefox that is not enough...

This is a part of it, without all the path (and before a try things on it):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="320" height="86" viewBox="0 0 320 86">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            .cls-1 {
                fill: transparent;
                fill-rule: evenodd;
                stroke: #fff;
                stroke-width: 6px;
            }
        </style>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <use xlink:href="#cls-1-path"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <path d="M319.604,36.098 C319.409,...5.551 103.736,5.687 103.192,5.881 Z" class="cls-1" id="cls-1-path" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Do you have any idea about what I should do ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not that there isn't anything at all. You just chose a `fill: transparent;` with a `#fff` white stroke on a `#ffffff` background.

**White on white appears invisible :-)**

Maybe FireFox does interpret the `#fff` differently than other browsers - as `#FFFFFF` and not as `#FFF000`.

For completeness, I attach my (minimally modified) test case:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="320" height="86" viewBox="0 0 320 86">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            .cls-1 {
                fill: transparent;
                fill-rule: evenodd;
                stroke: #fff444;
                stroke-width: 6px;
            }
        </style>
        <path id="cls-1-path" d = "M 0 0 L 550 230 L 160 0"/>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <use xlink:href="#cls-1-path"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <path d="M319.604,36.098 C319.409, 5.551 103.736,5.687 103.192,5.881 Z" class="cls-1" id="cls-1-path" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: But my background isn't white :/

Comment: @krawitz: Have you tried my test case from above? All I did was changing the stroke color and adding the path `<path id="cls-1-path" d = "M 0 0 L 550 230 L 160 0"/>` so that it's not empty.